# Auto Generated Report, server side

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have a web application(j2ee), where user can enter various data and can generate reports also. Now client wants to generate report automatically(every hour). What could be the best solution for this?

Comment: Is your app shared or used only by one client ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Shared application.
There are more than 250 users. I need to generate a particular report automatically hourly basis. After that I could send it to ftp to some selected user